# Como actualizar TClientDataSet al cambiar DBEdit

Tags: delphi

Tengo un campo precio en un TClientDataSet que viene de la base de datos pero es calculado, es decir esta guardado, pero si o si respeta una formula de acuerdo a costo de flete e impuestos.

La formula funciona bien matematicamente y la tengo en el evento afterpost:

```
procedure TDataModule1.cdsproductosAfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
 with DataModule1 do
 begin
DataModule1.cdsproductos.Open;

DataModule1.cdsproductos.Edit;
cdsproductosprecioactual.AsFloat:=cdsproductosCosto.AsFloat* 
(cdsproductosGanancia.AsFloat/100)+       
cdsproductosCosto.AsFloat+cdsproductosRedondeo.AsFloat + (cdsproductosCosto.AsFloat * 
(cdsproductosImpuesto.AsFloat/100))+cdsproductosFlete.AsFloat;


end;
end;
```

Entonces mi pregunta es:como actualizo el DBEdit de precio al cambiar un DBEDit cualquiera de los que influyen en laformula, ejemplo: al cambiar el costo debe cambiar el precio y guardarse sin necesidad de dar click en el boton guardar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes valerte del evento `OnChange` de los campos que forman parte de la fórmula, de esta manera el `Precio` se actualizará *automaticamente* cada vez que cambie el valor de cualquiera de estos campos, sin esperar hasta después de hacer *post* en el registro.

Para lograrlo, puedes arrancar factorizando el código de la fórmula en un método separado, digamos:

```
type
  TDataModule1 = class(TDataModule)
  // declaraciones...
  private
    procedure CalcularPrecio;
    // y más declaraciones...
  end;


  procedure TDataModule1.CalcularPrecio;
  begin
    cdsproductosprecioactual.AsFloat := 
        cdsproductosCosto.AsFloat * (cdsproductosGanancia.AsFloat/100)
      + cdsproductosCosto.AsFloat
      + cdsproductosRedondeo.AsFloat 
      + cdsproductosCosto.AsFloat * (cdsproductosImpuesto.AsFloat/100)
      + cdsproductosFlete.AsFloat;
  end;
```

Entonces, digamos que este cálculo debe lanzarse siempre que cambie alguno de los campos `Costo`, `Redondeo`, `Ganancia`, `Impuesto` (no sé si se me escapó alguno, pero ya te haces una idea), puedes escribir manejadores para el evento `OnChange` de cada uno de estos campos e invocar al método `CalcularPrecio`, que se vería algo como:

```
procedure TDataModule1.cdsproductosCostoChange(Sender: TField);
begin
  CalcularPrecio;
end;

procedure TDataModule1.cdsproductosRedondeoChange(Sender: TField);
begin
  CalcularPrecio;
end;

//etc...
```

### Buenas prácticas

He observado que utilizas una sentencia `with` en tu código, de esta manera:

```
procedure TDataModule1.cdsproductosAfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  with DataModule1 do
  begin
    ....
  end
end;
```

No sé exactamente lo que pretendes lograr, pero a mi manera de ver esta sentencia, no solo no es necesaria, sino que está de más y podría ocasionarte problemas si en el futuro llegas a crear más de una instancia de la clase en tiempo de corrida. Cuando se lanza cualquier método de la clase `TDataModule1` ya tienes acceso a todos los miembros de la clase para la instancia sobre la que se lanzó el método. No hace falta referenciar estos miembros con una variable.

También he visto otro par de detalles:

- Utilizas el método `AfterPost` para modificar datos del mismo registro que acabas de insertar/actualizar en la tabla subyacente en la base de datos (entiendo que no es lo que quieres en el caso del `Precio`, pero si aún lo utilizas en otros casos, te recomiendo hacerlo en el `BeforePost`, que se lanza justo antes de enviar la inserción/modificación al motor.

  Esto evitará que algún registro se pueda quedar desactualizado en el dataset si algo falla durante la ejecución del `AfterPost`.
- Los métodos `BeforePost`/`AfterPost` y, en general, la mayoría de los del *DataSet* se lanzan mientras el conjunto de datos está abierto, no hace falta *abrirlo*, cosa que haces en la primera línea de código:

  ```
  DataModule1.cdsproductos.Open;
  ```

  Esa línea está de más, pues este evento jamás se va a lanzar sobre un conjunto de datos cerrado.